# Updating RecyclerView Fragment adapter from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a MainActivity that holds `Fragment` with `RecyclerView` inside. The fragment initiates with "*supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add*" as you can see below in MainActiviry code. MainActivity is registered to some CallBack that alters moviesArrayList, and when it happens I need to update the Frgamnet with new moviesArrayList and reload the adapter. What is a suitable approach for this? Removing and adding Fragment again? Updating the Instance? Sending data to fragment via callback?

Main Activity:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        var moviesArrayList: ArrayList<Movie>? = ArrayList()

        //moviesArrayList //Some initializtion here

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, ListFragment.newInstance(moviesArrayList))
                .commitNow()
        }
    }
```

ListFragment:

```
class ListFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var  moviesArrayList: ArrayList<Movie>


interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    fun onFragmentInteraction(movie: Movie)
    fun onFragmentInteraction()
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false)

    val listView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.list2)

    listView.adapter = MyMovieRecyclerViewAdapter(moviesArrayList,object : OnItemClickListener {
        override fun onItemClicked(movie: Movie) {
            //Some on click happening
        }
    })

    return view
}

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(movies: ArrayList<Movie>?) = ListFragment().apply {
        if (movies != null) {
            moviesArrayList = movies //init moviesArrayList
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

When you sense there is a change in the list you simple call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

and that should update the recyclerview

Comment: This is not the question

Comment: Why not? When the list is altered you update the adapter which will display the new list..

Comment: The question is not how to update the adapter. The question is how to update Fragment with new data.